# Convert regexp from JavaScript to PCRE format

Tags: php, regex, pcre

Seen many questions on same topic here, but didn't find the answer :(

I've got this `{{Infobox[^]*?({{[^{}]*?}}[^]*?)*}}` regex. Works as a charm in Javascript and here http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/

In PHP it produces an error "Compilation failed: missing terminating ] for character class at offset 41".

I know about delimiters, also tried putting \ before { and } — didn't help.

```
{{For|the title track of the album|Master of Puppets (song)}}
{{Infobox Album <!-- See Wikipedia:WikiProject_Albums -->
| Name        = Master of Puppets
| Type        = Studio album
| Artist      = [[Metallica]]
| Cover       = Metallica - Master of Puppets.jpg
| Released    = {{Start date|1986|3|3}}
| Recorded    = September 1 – December 27, 1985 at [[Sweet Silence Studios]], [[Copenhagen]], [[Denmark]]
| Genre       = [[Thrash metal]]
| Length      = 54:41
| Label       = [[Elektra Records|Elektra]], [[Music for Nations]], [[Vertigo Records|Vertigo]]
| Producer    = Metallica, [[Flemming Rasmussen]]
| Last album  = ''[[Ride the Lightning]]''<br/>(1984)
| This album  = '''''Master of Puppets'''''<br/>(1986)
| Next album  = ''[[...And Justice for All (album)|...And Justice for All]]''<br/>(1988)
| Misc        = {{Singles
  | Name           = Master of Puppets
  | Type           = Studio
  | single 1       = [[Master of Puppets (song)|Master of Puppets]]
  | single 1 date  = July 2, 1986
  | single 2       = [[Battery (song)|Battery]]
  | single 2 date  = 1986
  | single 3       = [[Welcome Home (Sanitarium)]]
  | single 3 date  = 1986
  }}
}}
'''''Master of Puppets''''' is the third studio album by the American [[heavy metal music|heavy metal]] band [[Metallica]]. It was released on March 3, 1986 through [[Elektra Records]]. The album reached #29<ref>{{Cite news 
  | last = Pareles
  | first = Jon
  | coauthors = 
  | title = HEAVY METAL, WEIGHTY WORDS
  | work = [[The New York Times]]
  | place = USA
  | page = 8
  | language = 
  | publisher = The New York Times Company
  | date = 10 July 1988
  | url = http://www.nytimes.com/1988/07/10/magazine/heavy-metal-weighty-words.html?pagewanted=8
  | accessdate = 14 November 2010}}</ref> on the U.S. [[Billboard 200|''Billboard'' 200]] album chart and was the band's first gold record for sales of over 500,000 copies. This was done without any radio airplay or the release of a music video. The album eventually was certified 6x platinum by the [[Recording Industry Association of America|RIAA]].<ref>{{cite web|title=Gold & Platinum|url=http://riaa.com/goldandplatinumdata.php?resultpage=1&table=SEARCH_RESULTS&action=&title=Master%20of%20Puppets&artist=Metallica&format=&debutLP=&category=&sex=&releaseDate=&requestNo=&type=&level=&label=&company=&certificationDate=&awardDescription=&catalogNo=&aSex=&rec_id=&charField=&gold=&platinum=&multiPlat=&level2=&certDate=&album=&id=&after=&before=&startMonth=1&endMonth=1&startYear=1958&endYear=2008&sort=Artist&perPage=25|publisher=RIAA|accessdate=2009-12-31}}</ref>
```

Comment: can you show the string that u are trying to match?

Comment: Offset 41?  Your RE isn't even that long.  Is there something missing?

Comment: Trying to parse Wikipedia articles. Added the example to initial post. Missing the word "album", but that doesn't matter — "Compilation failed: missing terminating ] for character class at offset 35"

Comment: are your trying to parse html with regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the usage of `[^]` is misleading/not clear, I am not sure about its meaning.

*(Because you are getting an error about a missing `]`, I would assume it opens a character class, the `^` is the negation of the class and the following `]` does not close the class, it is its first member. But because Regexr is using it differently I think the meaning differs in the different regex engines.)*

You can try this one instead

```
{{Infobox[^{]*?({{[^}]*?}}[\s\S]*?)*}}
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2u6jn)

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the problem is with `^`, `{` and `}` characters not being escaped - you should try it with:

```
\{\{Infobox[\^]*?(\{\{[\^\{\}]*?\}\}\[^]*?)*\}\}
```

**Edit** to match any character with `[^]`:

```
\{\{Infobox.*?(\{\{[.\{\}]*?\}\}\.*?)*\}\}
```

Comment: If I escape ^ regex doesn't match anything in PHP and http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/   As for {} — I tried to escape them — didn't help.

Comment: I don't think the OP wants the carets escaped.  The expression `[^]` is one way to write "any character" which is what is being attempted: any character until the next `{{` which *does* need to be escaped.

Comment: *any character* should be matched with `.` - `^` inside `[]` means `NOT the following character` and he does not have any character after that